# NSData from plist displayed in UIWebView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiwebview, plist

In my application I stored some data in a plist as an `NSData`, and now I want to display this data in a `UIWebView`. How can I read a path from the plist and show this data as an image?

Please give me sample code for this.

Thanks in advance. I am new in iPhone programming, and i am suffering from this problem. Please help me.

Comment: Please provide sample code showing how you saved the plist and what was in it.

Answer (score 0):

firstly read the data from plist:

```
NSString *DownloadsPlistPath =[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Downloads" ofType:@"plist"];
mDownloadsArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:DownloadsPlistPath];
```

retrieve the content of file based on requirement (NSString,NSData,NSmutableArray etc).

now i you can use this data in UIWebView